# Reverting changes to a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem where a user may need to merge 2 parent entities together joining all the children into a single parent, this part is easy however i also need the ability to revert these changes back if need be.

So for example;

Lets say I have a John and a Dave, they both have 2 assets each and i want to transfer Dave's assets to John which will be done by simply swapping Dave's asset 'OWNERPKID' to Johns ID.

So far there are 2 tables `Person`, `Asset` and the link is contained in the asset table.

I am wondering if there is anything within SQL that can track this change and can revert it back if need be.  I am also aware that John may also give his assets to someone else which then really starts to complicate things if we want to revert things back.

Is there also something to handle this event?

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?

Comment: thanks for all the revisions haha, how do i apply them :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Transactions!  In SQL (assuming MSSQL because nothing was specified) you can start a transaction using the command `BEGIN TRANSACTION`.  Then, there are two options for closing the transaction: you can either `COMMIT TRANSACTION` or `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`.  `COMMIT` saves the changes to your DB and `ROLLBACK` reverts any changes that were done during the transaction.

Do some research on Transactions and I'm pretty sure you'll find what you're looking for.

Comment: Hmm....unless you mean you want to make the change, do a bunch of validation and THEN maybe rollback.  In that case you would need to take a DB backup before making your change and then RESTORE it, if need be.

Comment: will this transaction carry over several days?........ the example i gave is just an example but lets say we transfer a bunch of records to another person and a day later we decide we want to put them back (assuming no transactions happened since) is that possible?

Comment: @ kalimo this is a very active DB and we need need to have a specific set of data restored if this happens not the whole DB

Comment: @PaulS a transaction CAN stay open for days but, until it's `COMMIT`ed, the changes won't persist in the database. We're also starting to get into some possible locking issues at this point too.  Transactions are only for when you want to revert something immediately if something goes wrong.

Comment: For what you're trying to do, it looks more like taking an export of the table's data (into a CSV, for example) and then turning that data into a "populate" script would be a possible approach.  Or, creating a backup table in your DB that you could JOIN to to perform the reverse of your current update.  However, I'm starting to get a little far afield and ever-so-slightly hackish.

Comment: Ahh, my issue is the user may want to merge something..... the way things are working here i want a way for the USER to under a mistake with a merge..... i also want to be able to track the merges because the 'Parent' Records may be reverted at a later date but obviously without the related children as they (you might call it) have expired......

Comment: these merges are few and far between, it will happen when there is a need to either say join 2 items together maybe permanently or temporarily, after the merge its expected that all related records to the merge are tranferred too. the time may come when the merge will be undone to the original condition but obvious all related records to the children will be lost (not actually lost but expired or no longer needed) so the parent return to there original state.

Comment: however i want a backup for when a mistake is made during this merge so that it can be returned to its original state (likely immediately after the merge) but this is not automatic the user will trigger this

Comment: It seems like this cannot be achieved internally so i may have to resort in keeping duplicate tables or at least tracking some tables and expect to loose a little functionality since its going to be very difficult to pull this off....